# Is it safe to upgrade to OS X Lion for monotouch developers?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to upgrade to OS X Lion but I'm afraid it will mess up my development environment for monotouch. Will upgrading be fairly painless?

Comment: What's with the close votes? I thought this question was pretty relevant to programming or software development.

Comment: I second that. But at least you have found an answer. I am in the exact same situation, getting this "ibtool" error. Did you upgrade to Xcode4 or is there still an Xcode3 version?

Comment: Thanks for the support on the close votes. You can get it on the [app store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12). Also, see the update in my answer for the other issue I recently ran into.

Comment: Yea closing this as off topic is a major fail I am using monotouch myself to "PROGRAM" Iphone and Ipad apps.  I had the same issue so thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the support Joe. If you're able, vote to reopen the issue.

Comment: Edit: Here my blog that I did to get around all the issues of using current monotouch on Lion. http://joemele.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/monotouch-and-lion/

Comment: I have just gotten around to installing Lion and I have run into the ibtool not found issue also.  Personally I can't understand why this question was closed either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't have a problem upgrading aside from the fact that I had to upgrade Xcode to the version built for Lion.

If you upgrade and try to build your iPhone project and you get an error saying it can't find `ibtool` then upgrading Xcode will solve this.

One other thing that I ran into (after upgrading Xcode) is a bug where the iOS simulator could not find the right version of the SDK libs. I'm not sure if this is monotouch related but you can find the bug report [here](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52) and what I did to get around it.

**Update:** Ok. It seems like there are more problems than I realized. Here's another example. Debugging the simulator causes MonoDevelop to crash at random points. See [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/monotouch@lists.ximian.com/msg00842.html).

Comment: We're preparing to release Mono 2.10.3 with some MacOSX Lion fixes, including: a Socket.BeginConnect() hang fix and 2 Gtk+ bugs that would cause any Gtk# app (like MonoDevelop) to crash. Also note that MonoTouch 4.0.4.1 includes a MacOSX Lion fix for activation.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to it.